# How to make MySQL Database calls in Tornado for an application with highly scalable infrastructure which makes a high number of database queries?

Tags: python, mysql, asynchronous, tornado, mysql-python

So which will be a better method to make database calls in Tornado for a high performance application with highly scalable infrastructure which makes a high number of database queries?

**Method 1** : So I have come across async database drivers/clients like TorMySQL, Tornado-Mysql, asynctorndb,etc which can perform async database calls.

**Method 2** : Use the general and common MySQLdb or mysqlclient (by PyMySQL) drivers and make the database calls to separate backend services and load-balance the calls with nginx.
Similar to what the original Friendfeed guys did which they mentioned in one of the groups,

Bret Taylor, one of the original authors, writes :

> groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/9a08f5f08cdab108
>
> We experimented with different async DB approaches, but settled on
>   synchronous at FriendFeed because generally if our DB queries were
>   backlogging our requests, our backends couldn't scale to the load
>   anyway. Things that were slow enough were abstracted to separate
>   backend services which we fetched asynchronously via the async HTTP
>   module.

Other supporting links for **Method 2** for better understanding what I am trying to say are:

- [StackOverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24701591/5787174)

**Method 3** : By making use of threads and IOLoop and using the general sync libraries.

Supporting example links to explain what I mean,

- What the Tornado wiki says, https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/wiki/Threading-and-concurrency

> Do it synchronously and block the IOLoop. This is most appropriate for
>   things like memcache and database queries that are under your control
>   and should always be fast. If it's not fast, make it fast by adding
>   the appropriate indexes to the database, etc.

- Another sample Method :

  For sync database(mysqldb), we can

  executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(4)

  result = yield executor.submit(mysqldb_operation)

**Method 4** : Just use sync drivers like MySQLdb and start enough Tornado Instances and load balance using nginx that the application remains asynchronous on a broader level with some calls being blocked but other requests benefit the asynchronous nature via the large number of tornado instances.

'Explanation' :

For details follow this link - www.jjinux.com/2009/12/python-asynchronous-networking-apis-and.html, which says :

> They allow MySQL queries to block the entire process. However, they
>   compensate in two ways. They lean heavily on their asynchronous web
>   client wherever possible. They also make use of multiple Python
>   processes. Hence, if you're handling 500 simultaneous request, you
>   might use nginx to split them among 10 different Tornado Web
>   processes. Each process is handling 50 simultaneous requests. If one
>   of those requests needs to make a call to the database, only 50
>   (instead of 500) requests are blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FriendFeed used what you call "method 4": there was no separate backend service; the process was just blocked during the database call.

Using a completely asynchronous driver ("method 1") is generally best. However, this means that you can't use synchronous libraries that wrap the database operations like SQLAlchemy. In this case you may have to use threads ("method 3"), which is almost as good (and easier than "method 2").

The advantage of "method 4" is that it is easy. In the past this was enough to recommend it because introducing callbacks everywhere was tedious; with the advent of coroutines method 3 is almost as easy so it is usually better to use threads than to block the process.

Comment: Thanks Ben! So let me get this straight, Please let me know for all my 3 doubts.

Comment: Doubt 1 -  are you suggesting If I am to consider one of the methods, then I should go for method 1, if not then method 3, and if not it, only then method 4? Is this what you are suggesting?

Comment: Doubt 2 - If method 1 is better than method 3, then why in the Tornado wiki, they mention using method 3, and if not then to consider the method 1, the link is -> https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/wiki/Threading-and-concurrency

Comment: Doubt 3 - I think my method 2 and method 4 are actually same. Aren't they?  If yes then let me know, if not. then tell me the difference.

Comment: Yes, 2 and 4 are the same, and the preference should be for 1, 3, and 2/4 in that order. That wiki page is 4 years old and predates the existence of coroutines; it needs to be updated.

Comment: Okay. Got it. If possible suggest me some aysnc libraries for method 1, I have asked this in different post's comment section too. Well, consider my requirements are for a highly scalable system which may have a huge number of database queries.